How to save PyCharm (JetBrains) tab layout?
When working with PyCharm (or other JetBrains tools) I often need to have multiple (e.g. 20) different tabs opened on my screen. It takes quite a lot every time I open the IDE, to arrange their splitting according to my preference. How can I store the layout so that every time I restart the app, I don't have to re-arrange the tabs?
I tried to save the current layout, however on restart, I see the stored tabs to be arranged in a single window and not the way I had split them.
